# Getting an Unexpected Token syntax error when using a third party React library that has no syntax errors

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use [React-ElasticSearch](https://react-elasticsearch.raph.site/). The problem is that whenever I'm trying to using any of their components in my code, I get an Unexpected Token syntax error in line 25 of the [ActiveFilters.js](https://github.com/betagouv/react-elasticsearch/blob/master/src/ActiveFilters.js) file.

```
  23 | 
  24 |   return (
> 25 |     <div className="react-es-active-filters">
     |     ^
  26 |       {items ? (
  27 |         items(activeFilters, removeFilter)
  28 |       ) : (
```

It doesn't look like there are any syntax errors in this file. What can it be?

Comment: Is the same error happening once the component returns only an empty `<div>` element and you remove the `{items}` part?

Comment: @norbitrial, I can't. This is an external library.

Comment: If you are using a library, then the code should be compiled to javascript. There shouldn't be `JSX`.